# How to do partial derivatives in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm working on a code in a group for a class. One of the biggest obstacles is figuring out a code to do partial derivatives. Octave is similar to Matlab syntax wise but it does not do symbols "sym". I'm kinda stuck as to how to go about doing a partial derivative in the program. It has to be done in Octave, it cannot be done in Matlab.

Comment: Have you considered using the `symbolic` package for Octave? It does what you want: http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/. List of available functions here: http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/overview.html

Answer (score 5):

Basically just parroting what @rayryeng has said in his comment, but a small self-contained example to find the partial derivative of `y(x, z) = x^2 + z^2` with respect to `x`:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms x z
y = x^2 + z^2
diff(y, x)
```

Gives the result:

```
ans = (sym) 2*x
```

Which is the correct partial derivative of `y` with respect to `x`. Note that to get this to work you will have to install the [symbolic package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/). I found that I also needed to have the python package `SymPy` installed. There are some helpful instructions [here](https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/wiki/Notes-on-Windows-installation).

Comment: Using similar syntax, how can I take full derivative?